# passing two array in mysql different sizes one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
     $str = implode(',',$name);
        function trim_value(&$value) 
        { 
         $value = trim($value);

        $Array = explode(',', $str);


       array_walk($myArray, 'trim_value');

for($x=0; $x<count($myArray); $x++){

      var_dump($Array[$x], $sports[$x]);
      }
       //this is just a portion of the code this is the part that's causing   the problem
         ?>


<input name="name[]"/><!--John Doe, Jane Doe-->
<input name="sports[]"/><!--tennis-->

<input name="name[]"/><!--William Doe-->
<input name="sports[]"/><!--football-->
```

suppose i want to pass name which is comma seprated names in the mysql database but i would like to implode then explode to split up the strings in an array to store then in there own respective rows. How would one write the php to do so using for loop.

so in the database the rows would look like row 1=John Doe| tennis |, row 2=Jane doe |tennis |, row 3=William Doe |football|. Inputs are generated dynamically using jquery. i have written a code to that addmore fields dynamically upon button click.

Tried doing it but i keep getting the first sports which is tennis applied to all the rows i want them to link just as i have stated. HELP!! HELP!! HELP!!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry i got overwhelmed  and deleted everything now i am starting over from scratch. i just need a kick start

Comment: How exactly do you want your input fields to show up? Like an input box with a single sport followed by an input box with multiple names?

Comment: @ Object Manipulator the comment beside the boxes are just the example of the inputs that i user would input so for the sports box only one sports is allowed. and then the user can have multiple persons playing one sports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetched records need to be customized into a multi dimensional array such that one sport can have multiple sportsmen.

```
$rows = array(
  "John Doe| tennis |",
  "Jane doe |tennis |", 
  "William Doe |football|"
);

foreach($rows as $row) { 
    $fields = array_filter(explode("|", $row));   // Breaking up when | appears. Filtering is preferred because the last entry can return blank sometimes.
    $sportmen[trim($fields[1])][] = $fields[0];  // $fields[1] contain the sport. And $field[0] contain the player name.
}
```

So far, the $sportsmen array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [tennis] => Array
    (
        [0] => John Doe
        [1] => Jane doe 
    )

   [football] => Array
    (
        [0] => William Doe 
    )

)
```

Now, we simply need to loop through this array.

```
 <?php   foreach($sportmen as $sport => $players) { ?>
    <input name="name[]" value="<?php echo implode(",", $players); ?>" />
    <input name="sports" value="<?php echo $sport; ?>" />
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ok the last php is for it to display in the input box. thanks alot. i just need the top part though so i am going to try it and see if it passes the values to mysql

Comment: so for the first code the input fields would be like                                   <input name="name[][]"/><!--John Doe, Jane Doe-->
<input sports="sports[][]"/><!--tennis-->

<input name="name[][]"/><!--William Doe-->
<input sports="sports[][]"/><!--football-->

Comment: Please see that name is an HTML attribute. It should be <input name="name[]" ... > and <input name="sports" .. > not <input sports="sports[]"/>

Comment: to get it in multi dimensional array format would i need to do what i commented above?

Comment: Just stick to what's mentioned in the answer. It should work just fine.

Comment: yes but remember they are separate input fields so i have 4 input field the reason why is because they are dynamically generated. so they have to be in an array. i can have up to 10 input fields if i push the addmore button i have created using jquery.

Comment: Trying it but its not working. It seems i am not understanding what you are doing with the foreach loop